# MySQL source file quietly

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

I have a number of really large files with many insert statements (18.7 million in the largest one). At the `mysql>` prompt if I do a `source file.sql` or a `./file.sql` everything works good, things get inserted, but there is output for every run statement which ways: `Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)`.

When run this way these inserts can take a very long time. **Is there a way to run sql queries quietly, with no output?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can direct them straight into the mysql client:

```
mysql -u... -p my_database < file.sql
```

Comment: Thanks. The main reason I was concerned about this was that I thought the output was slowing it down. After running your solution it didn't seem to speed it up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) copy the file to the database machine and run it locally. 2) Use fewer statements, inserting multiple items at once.

Comment: Just copying the files to the database machine made all the difference in the world. Thanks Keith.

Comment: Down voted because this method of importing can corrupt UTF and binary data. Sourcing the file the correct way to do this.

Comment: @Geoffrey, so what is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Dikla In the mysql client run `source /path/to/file.sql;`

Comment: @Geoffrey, I just tried, even with the semi-colon it is still generating output.

Comment: what if i run this, and i want the inverse, `mysql -u... -p my_database < file.sql` but to show the output as source do ?

Answer (score 2):

I run on the command line:

```
>mysql -p <Database> < file.sql
```

I dont get output that way.